# Resample a dataframe with different aggregate functions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-resample

I have a data frame like the below, which has a 'Stats' column containing different statistical values(avg, count, min, max) for every 1-sec timestamp.

| Timestamps | Location | Service | Status Code | Stats | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1656533176875 | A | s1 | 200 | count | 5000 |
| 1656533176875 | A | s1 | 500 | avg. | 3000 |
| .... | .... | .... | .... | ... | ... |
| 1656533176878 | B | s2 | 504 | max. | 6000 |

Now from this data frame, I have to resample the data for a user-defined time interval, say for a 5-minutes interval, and aggregate the values for that interval. As the values represent different aggregations, I need to apply different aggregate functions for different parts of the data frame. For example, if I want to resample for 5 minutes of data, I need to apply the average if the 'Stats' is 'avg' or apply the sum if the 'Stats' is count. Also, the grouping has to be by centers, service, and status code.
I have written this code so far but I am unable to get the desired result.

```
        #sample dataframe
        rng = pd.date_range('2022-06-01', periods=10, freq='T')
        np.random.seed(10)
        l = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
        k = ['avg', 'max', 'min', 'count', 'median', 'std']
        m = ['s1', 's2', 's3']
        j = [200, 400, 404, 500]

        df = pd.DataFrame(
            {'date_time': rng,
             'location': random.choices(l, k=10),
             'service': random.choices(m, k=10),
             'status': random.choices(j, k=10),
             'stat': random.choices(k, k=10),
             'value': np.random.randint(100, 900, size=10)
             }
        )

        df.sort_values(by=df.columns.to_list())
        print(df)
        interval =5
        resampled_df = df.assign(
            n_count=np.where(df['stat'] == 'count'),
            n_median=np.where(df['stat'] == 'median'),
            n_max=np.where(df['stat'] == 'max'),
            n_min=np.where(df['stat'] == 'min'),
            n_avg=np.where(df['stat'] == 'avg'),
            n_std=np.where(df['stat'] == 'std'),
        ).groupby(['date_time', 'location', 'services', 'status_code', 'stat']) \
            .resample('{}min'.format(interval), on='date_time') \
            .value \
            .agg({'n_count': sum, 'n_avg': np.mean, 'n_max': max, 'n_min': min, 'n_std': np.std,
                  'n_median': np.median})

        print(resampled_df)
```

I get the error ValueError: Length of values (1) does not match the length of index (10). The expected result is resampled data for 5 minutes with aggregated value depending on the 'Stats' column.

Comment: What is your question here?

Comment: @ScottBoston how can I use different aggregate functions based on a column values when I resample for a given time period

Comment: Can you create data and expected output from this data?  Hard to test and get exactly what you need without verifying data.

Comment: @ScottBoston I have created sample data. Would you kindly check now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not sure exactly what your output should look like, but here is an attempt:

```
agg_dict = {'avg':'mean',
            'count':'count',
            'max':'max',
            'median':'median',
            'std':'std'}
interval = 2
df.pivot(['date_time', 'location', 'service', 'status'],
          'stat', 
          'value')\
  .reset_index(level=[1,2,3])\
  .rename_axis('date_time')\
  .groupby(['date_time', 'location', 'service', 'status']) \
            .resample(f'{interval}T')\
            .agg(agg_dict)\
            .reset_index(level=0, drop=True)\
            .stack()\
            .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
   location service  status           date_time    stat      0
0         B      s1     200 2022-06-01 00:00:00   count    0.0
1         B      s1     200 2022-06-01 00:00:00     max  482.0
2         B      s2     500 2022-06-01 00:00:00     avg  753.0
3         B      s2     500 2022-06-01 00:00:00   count    0.0
4         A      s2     200 2022-06-01 00:02:00   count    0.0
5         A      s2     200 2022-06-01 00:02:00  median  442.0
6         D      s3     200 2022-06-01 00:02:00   count    0.0
7         D      s3     200 2022-06-01 00:02:00     max  898.0
8         A      s1     500 2022-06-01 00:04:00   count    1.0
9         B      s2     500 2022-06-01 00:04:00   count    0.0
10        D      s1     404 2022-06-01 00:06:00   count    0.0
11        A      s3     200 2022-06-01 00:06:00   count    0.0
12        B      s1     500 2022-06-01 00:08:00   count    1.0
13        B      s3     404 2022-06-01 00:08:00   count    0.0
14        B      s3     404 2022-06-01 00:08:00     max  383.0
```